# Unstructured When copy and paste a content element in Typo3 neos

Tags: neoscms

I am using Typo3 neos version 1.0.2 Beta

When copy content element and paste it in other content area
It will not page and instead it shows error and the content element with name unstructured is created in node tree.

ExtDirect error: Uncaught exception #1301610453 (ref 20140430165908d46739) - Could not resolve a route and its corresponding URI for the given parameters. This may be due to referring to a not existing package / controller / action while building a link or URI. Refer to log and check the backtrace for more details.

PLease let me know the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There were known issues with copy/paste functionality in Neos 1.0.x.

Please use Neos 1.1 (currently 1.1.0-beta2) where this issue seems to be fixed.